# Capitalization of a String

Tags: c++

I'm extremely new to C++ and I have an assignment to first format a name provided via the user, and then ensure it has proper capitalization (First letter capital, rest lowercase).

I feel like I have the function correct, but the function involves an array and the code I have written does not seem to allow a string to be initialized to the array.

The output of the first stretch of code is then input into the capitalize function and that is where I am running into an error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

void capitalize(char str[]);

int main()
{
    //inputs user name in the format first, middle and last name
    string name;
    cout << "Enter your name in the order of first middle last: ";
    getline(cin, name, '\n');

    //string variables to extract the first. middle and last names
    //from the input
    string first, last, middle, subOutput;



    // finds the poisiton of first space
    int firstblank = name.find(' ', 0);


    // taken as first name until the first space
    first = name.substr(0, firstblank);


    // finds second space
    int secondblank = name.find(' ', firstblank + 1);


    // if second space is not found means no middle name in the input
    if (secondblank == -1)
    {
        // taken the remaining string as last name
        last = name.substr(firstblank + 1);
        // prepares name as desired output
        subOutput = last + ", " + first;
    }
    else
    {
        // gets middle name from firstspace to second space
        middle = name.substr(firstblank + 1, secondblank - firstblank - 1);
        // gets last name
        last = name.substr(secondblank + 1);
        //prepares output
        subOutput = last + ", " + first + " " + middle.at(0) + ".";
    }

    char O[] = subOutput;
    capitalize(O);
    cout << O << endl;


    //displays output
    //cout << O << endl;

    return 0;
}

void capitalize(char str[]) {
    if (strlen(str) == 0) {
        return;
    }
    str[0] = toupper(str[0]);
    for (int i = 1; i < strlen(str); i++)
    {
        str[1] = tolower(str[i]);
    }
}
```

Might be a very basic fix but like I said, I am very new to coding/C++ so any help is greatly appreciated!

EDIT: 
I actually revised my code and I believe I have some of the solution, however
there is a bug that I am unsure about. 
New Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

const int CAPACITY = 1000;


void capitalize(string& str);


int main()
{
    //inputs user name in the format first, middle and last name
    //string variables to extract the first. middle and last names
    string name, first, last, middle, subOutput, Output;
    cout << "Enter your name in the order of first middle last: ";
    getline(cin, name, '\n');


    //from the input




    // finds the poisiton of first space
    int firstblank = name.find(' ', 0);


    // taken as first name until the first space
    first = name.substr(0, firstblank);


    // finds second space
    int secondblank = name.find(' ', firstblank + 1);


    // if second space is not found means no middle name in the input
    if (secondblank == -1)
    {
        // taken the remaining string as last name
        last = name.substr(firstblank + 1);
        // prepares name as desired output
        subOutput = last + ", " + first;
    }
    else
    {
        // gets middle name from firstspace to second space
        middle = name.substr(firstblank + 1, secondblank - firstblank - 1);
        // gets last name
        last = name.substr(secondblank + 1);
        //prepares output
        subOutput = last + ", " + first + " " + middle.at(0) + ".";
    }


    capitalize(subOutput);
    Output = subOutput;
    cout << Output << endl;



    return 0;
}



void capitalize(string& str) {
    if (str.length() == 0) {
        return;
    }
    str[0] = toupper(str[0]);
    for (int i = 1; i < str.length(); i++)
    {
        str[i] = tolower(str[i]);
    }
}
```

The code compiles and formats properly, however when capitalizing, it only properly capitalizes the last name properly. I am not sure how I can get it to capitalize everything though. Like I said, any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: `str[1]` --> `str[i]`

Answer (score 3):

Use to `std::toupper(string[0])` to capitalise the first character. It's builtin function.

Answer (score 1):

When you are in c++. Why C-Styled char array. Library string has so m inbuilt function try them. Try this instead. C style arrays are often error-prone. Try to use C++ functions and libraries.

```
int main()
{
string s;
getline(cin,s);
decltype(s.size()) i = 0;
do{
if(i==0 || isspace(s[i-1]))
{
    s[i] = toupper(s[i]);
}
else{
    s[i] = tolower(s[i]);
    }

++i;
}while(i!= s.size());
cout<<s;
return 0;}
```

comment if you found it hard to understand.

Comment: why decltype, if you can use size::type, or much cleaner c++11 style for?

Comment: I'm not sure. Professor hasn't introduced them to us yet. I'm assuming she wants us to understand the C versions first before moving on.

Comment: That depends on you. I prefer decltype more. Btw you can use auto too or size::type as you said.

Comment: @JATX99 In your updated code, you are totally in C++. One side you said you want to implement in C, and now you are in C++. Stick to one thing and make logic. If you are in C++, try the above code. Btw what's the need to find 1st, 2nd, and remaining space. You are creating code unnecessarily long.

Comment: @JATX99 Learning C before C++ just means you'll have a lot of *un*learning to do. They are *very different* languages and learning C before C++ doesn't help you learn C++ - quite the opposite.

Answer (score 1):

You are already using many of the [std::basic_string](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) functions, why not simply use the `.begin()` and `.end()` iterators and iterate over each character in the string keeping track of the last (previous) character seen and if the last character was whitespace (or a `'.'` indicating an initial), capitalize the current character, otherwise set to lowercase?

It is actually shorter and simpler. All of the [std::basic_string](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) functions are listed. All you need do is:

```
...
#include <cctype>

/* convert string to Titlecase */
void strtotitle (std::string& name)
{
    char last = ' ';    /* initialize last as whitespace */

    for (std::string::iterator i = name.begin(); i != name.end(); i++) {
        if (isspace(last) || last == '.')
            *i = toupper(*i);   /* convert 1st in word toupper */
        else
            *i = tolower(*i);   /* convert remaining tolower */

        last = *i;              /* save current char as last */
    }
}
```

Adding a short `main()` to take the users input you could do:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>

/* convert string to Titlecase */
void strtotitle (std::string& name)
{
    char last = ' ';    /* initialize last as whitespace */

    for (std::string::iterator i = name.begin(); i != name.end(); i++) {
        if (isspace(last) || last == '.')
            *i = toupper(*i);   /* convert 1st in word toupper */
        else
            *i = tolower(*i);   /* convert remaining tolower */

        last = *i;              /* save current char as last */
    }
}

int main (void) {

    std::string name {};

    std::cout << "enter name: ";
    if (!getline (std::cin, name)) {
        std::cerr << "(user canceled input)\n";
        return 1;
    }

    strtotitle (name);
    std::cout << "formatted : " << name << "\n";
}
```

It provides much more flexibility than searching manually for the *first* or *second* space, etc..

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/name2title
enter name: alPHRED c. fudSTER
formatted : Alphred C. Fudster
```

or

```
$ ./bin/name2title
enter name: mICKEy mOUSe
formatted : Mickey Mouse
```

or

```
$ ./bin/name2title
enter name: m.m. disNey
formatted : M.M. Disney
```

You can also easily add an additional function to trim leading and trailing whitespace and compress multiple included whitespace to a single space allowing you to fully format even the strangest input.

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.